# Mysql - 'Select max' from multiple joined tables doesn't return correct values

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables - one is a list of addresses, and the other of attendance dates and EmployeeIDNumbers to identfy the engineer who attended.  An engineer may have attended an address multiple times.  I am trying to select the address name, and the most recent attendance date and corresponding engineerID

```
select s.sitename, max(sd.scheduleddate), sd.EngineerID
from sites as s 
left join scheduled_dates as sd on sd.idsites = s.idsites
group by s.idsites
```

This code correctly pulls each address and the most recent 'Scheduled Date' but does not pull the correct corresponding engineer id.  How do I get the engineerID from the same row as the max(scheduleddate)?  Think this is something to do with the 'greatest-n-per-group' discussion, but I can't see how to implement that code with a query that already has a join

Comment: Please add a create table and data to youtr question and also your mysql number. It usually works fine with min and max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
select s.sitename, sd.EngineerID, sd.scheduleddate
from sites as s 
inner join scheduled_dates as sd on sd.idsites = s.idsites
where not exists (
    select 1
    from scheduled_dates sd1
    where sd1.idsites = s.idsites
    and sd1.scheduleddate > sd.scheduleddate
)
```

The condition ensures that there no other record exists in `scheduled_dates` for the current site with a date greater than the one on the record being selected.

Notes: I turned you `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, since I believe that it better fit your use cases, feel free to revert this if needed.

Comment: that got it,  thanks for the prompt response.  I have tried to +1 your answer but can't due to being a newbie.  Now to look up the difference between an inner join and a left join.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
select s.sitename, sd.scheduleddate, sd.EngineerID
from sites s left join
     (select sd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sd.idsites orer by sd.scheduleddate desc) as seqnum
      from scheduled_dates sd
     ) sd
     on sd.idsites = s.idsites and sd.seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this also keeps all sites (which appears to be your intention), even those that have not been visited.